# Echo each file in Fileset with size, date and time

Tags: ant, file-listing

I'm converting a DOS batch file to Ant.  At the end of the batch file, I print out a list of files copied including size, date and time using the DOS `dir` command.  I would like to do the same at the end of the Ant script.  So far I have:

```
<!-- LIST COPIED FILES -->
<target name="summary" depends="backup">
    <fileset id="zipfiles" dir="${dest}" casesensitive="yes">
        <include name="*.zip"/>
    </fileset>  

    <property name="prop.zipfiles" refid="zipfiles"/>
    <echo>${prop.zipfiles}</echo>       
</target>
```

How can I modify the above to print each file on a separate line, with size, date and time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a solution based on an external Tasksuite called [Ant Flaka](http://code.google.com/p/flaka).
With Ant Flaka you get access to the underlying fileobjects and their properties (name,mtime,size..) from your fileset. no need to open an external process via apply/cmd

```
<project name="demo" xmlns:fl="antlib:it.haefelinger.flaka">
    <fl:install-property-handler />

    <!-- as fileset has no absolute pathnames we need
         path combined with pathconvert -->
    <path id="foobar">
        <fileset dir="/home/gilreb/Downloads">
            <include name="*.zip"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <pathconvert property="zipfiles" refid="foobar"/>

    <!-- iterate over the listentries, get access to
         the underlying fileobject and echo its properties -->
    <fl:for var="f" in="split('${zipfiles}', ':')">
        <echo>
      #{  format('filename %s, last modified %tD, size %s bytes', f.tofile.toabs,f.tofile.mtime,f.tofile.size)  }
     </echo>
    </fl:for>

</project>
```

output =

```
...  
   [echo]       filename /some/path/apache-ant-1.8.2-bin.zip, last modified 03/16/11, size 10920710 bytes
     [echo]      
     [echo]       filename /some/path/apache-ant-1.8.2-src.zip, last modified 03/16/11, size 8803388 bytes
     [echo]      
     [echo]       filename /some/path/apache-ant-antunit-1.1-bin.zip, last modified 04/17/11, size 70477 bytes
...
```

Comment: Thank you! I dropped in the jar, made slight mods to the EL and it just worked.  Flaka is a much needed addition to Ant.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that is available in any of the core Ant tasks.

You could write your own custom task to do this.

Alternatively, you could use the [Apply](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/apply.html) task to execute a system command like `dir` for each file in a fileset. For example:

```
<apply executable="cmd" osfamily="windows">
<arg value="/c"/>
<arg value="dir"/>
<fileset dir=".">
  <include name="*.zip"/>
</fileset>
</apply>
```

Following your comment below, you could check whether all your zip files were newer than some target file (which you could create before creation of the zips) using the [Uptodate](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/uptodate.html) task.

Comment: I'm surprised that such an external task isn't already out there.  Surely I'm not the first person to need this...?

Comment: I could do as you said and have Ant call the DOS `dir` command. My hope was to get the file date/time into an Ant property so I could compare before and after and do an alert if they hadn't changed, etc.

Comment: You may find other mechanisms in Ant to get the end result you need by a different route. I've updated my answer to mention an inbuilt mechanism to check file freshness.