# Ant get file creation timestamp

Tags: ant

I am writing a `manifest.xml` file during an Ant build for an OpenCMS project.

I need to be able to pull up a file's create date, and last modified date on a file. (Although the current process is giving each file a timestamp of `Wed, 31 Dec 1969 19:00:00 EST` anyway -- at least on Windows machines when they run the build.)

Is there a way I can pull up the creation date timestamp of a file in Ant? I'm using standard Ant tasks and Ant-Contrib tasks.

Comment: Here's a similar question with a solution based on Tasksuite Ant Flaka => http://stackoverflow.com/a/5992436/130683

Comment: @Rebse Thanks, I saw that. However, I don't have Flacka installed. I was hoping that someone knows of a way to use `<script>` and `<scriptdef>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your OS, f.e. Unix doesn't store the file creation time, [see details here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24441/get-file-created-creation-time)
Two possible solutions :

Solution 1, works on Windows only with Java >= 6, no addons needed

```
<project>
  <!-- Works on Windows only, uses the jdk builtin
       rhino javascript engine (since jdk6)
       use dir command without /T:C to get lastmodificationtime
  -->
  <macrodef name="getFileTimes">
    <attribute name="dir" />
    <attribute name="file" />
    <attribute name="setprop" default="@{file}_ctime" />
    <sequential>
      <exec executable="cmd" dir="@{dir}" outputproperty="@{setprop}">
        <arg value="/c" />
        <arg line="dir @{file} /T:C|find ' @{file}'" />
      </exec>
      <script language="javascript">
     tmp = project.getProperty("@{setprop}").split("\\s+") ;
     project.setProperty("@{setprop}", tmp[0] + "/" + tmp[1]) ;
   </script>
    </sequential>
  </macrodef>

  <getFileTimes dir="C:/tmp" file="bookmarks.html" />

  <echo>
  $${bookmarks.html_ctime} => ${bookmarks.html_ctime}
  </echo>
</project>
```

Solution 2, needs Java 7 and groovy-all-x.x.x.jar (contained in [groovy binary release](https://dl.bintray.com/groovy/maven/apache-groovy-binary-2.4.6.zip))
Adjust the SimpleDateFormat to your liking.
On Unix filesystems when asking for creationtime you'll get the last modification time.

```
<project>
  <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy"/>

  <!-- Solution for Java 7, uses the nio package
       needs groovy-all-2.1.0.jar
  -->
  <macrodef name="getFileTimes">
    <attribute name="file"/>
    <attribute name="ctimeprop" default="@{file}_ctime"/>
    <attribute name="mtimeprop" default="@{file}_mtime"/>
    <sequential>
      <groovy>
      import java.nio.file.*
      import java.nio.file.attribute.*
      import java.text.*
      import java.util.date.*

      Path path = Paths.get("@{file}")
      BasicFileAttributeView view = Files.getFileAttributeView(path, BasicFileAttributeView.class)
      BasicFileAttributes attributes = view.readAttributes()
      lastModifiedTime = attributes.lastModifiedTime()
      createTime = attributes.creationTime()
      DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss", Locale.US)
      df.format(new Date(createTime.toMillis()))

      properties.'@{ctimeprop}' = df.format(new Date(createTime.toMillis()))
      properties.'@{mtimeprop}' = df.format(new Date(lastModifiedTime.toMillis()))
     </groovy>
    </sequential>
  </macrodef>

  <getFileTimes file="C:/tmp/bookmarks.html"/>

  <echo>
    $${C:/tmp/bookmarks.html_ctime} => ${C:/tmp/bookmarks.html_ctime}
    $${C:/tmp/bookmarks.html_mtime} => ${C:/tmp/bookmarks.html_mtime}
  </echo>
</project>
```

I tried also using the builtin javascript engine, but i got errors like :

```
sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EvaluatorException: missing name after . operator
```

IMO, for simple things using javascript `<script language="javascript">` is sufficient, but if you need to import java packages etc. .. it's a PITA. Groovy simply works.

Comment: Actually, the Rhino JavaScript engine built into Java 1.6 and later gives you access to Java objects. I really had no problems with it. I tried pure JavaScript, but the on line documentation is bad. The Java documentation is a lot better. I can get the `cdate` in Unix using `<exec>` but that's iffy. Besides our official builds are done on Jenkins which sits on a Unix server. Thanks for the answer. Java 1.7 may be an option. However, we have standardized on Java 1.6 for now.

Comment: Even though I didn't use this, I still like your answer, so I'm giving you credit.

Comment: Getting the unix creation time depends upon the used filesystem, f.e. see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10171069/file-creation-time-in-unix

Comment: It's EOL for Java 6 after beeing extended 2 times (July 2012 -> November 2012 -> February 2013) => https://blogs.oracle.com/henrik/entry/updated_java_6_eol_date

Comment: End of life? My Mac is still running JDK 1.6.0_37 as most Macs are. And, my company has finally officially blessed JDK 1.6. Last year, I was working for a company that still used JDK 1.3. I believe Red Hat still has 1.6 as their officially supported release. When you talk about massive business systems, it's hard to get them to change anything. I have 1.7 on my Windows 7 (first Win7 PC I had. The one last year was still XP) and we're testing it out. Maybe we'll move over to 1.7 before 1.8 is EOL'd.

Comment: Creation time has always been tricky. When is a file a _new_ file? If I use `mv` to rename it, is it a new file, or just a changed name? If I used `mv` to move it? What if I use `cat foo > bar`? Is `bar` a new file? It's probably why the original developers settled on `lastModified` for the _creation time_.

Answer (score 4):

I've got this to work.

As [Mark O'Connor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14718827/368630) pointed out, you can't get the file creation time from earlier versions of Java. However, the original Java program that was being used for this task used the [lastModified](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#lastModified()) method for both the creation date and the last modified date<sup>1</sup>. I was fine doing the same thing.

I created a `<scriptdef>` to do pull the Last Modified date from a file. In Java 1.6 and up, you have access directly to the Rhino JavaScript library, so you no longer need the BeanShell library.

```
<scriptdef name="file.mdate" language="javascript"> 
    <attribute name="file"/> 
    <attribute name="property"/> 
        file_name = attributes.get("file"); 
        property_to_set = attributes.get("property");

        file = new java.io.File(file_name); 
        file_date = file.lastModified();

        date_format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss zzz");
        formated_date = date_format.format(new java.util.Date(file_date));
        project.setNewProperty(property_to_set, formated_date);
</scriptdef>
```

Once defined, I can use it as an Ant task:

```
<file.mdate
    file="${file.name}"
    property="file.modified.date"/>
<echo>The file "${file}" was modified on ${file.modified.date}</echo>
```

Comment: You may get the creationtime via systemcommand if OS==Windows, see my answer.

Comment: this solution is good, neat and simple. 3rd party library Groovy is not needed. just need to set the property of the file like:<property name="file.name" location="yourFilePath/yourFileName"/>. it should work on any system. Particularly, i ran it in my macbook.and its perfect. BIG THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Problem is the standard Java File object only supports a method for returning the last modified date:

- [How to discover a File's creation time with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32586/how-to-discover-a-files-creation-time-with-java)
- [Determine file creation date in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723838/determine-file-creation-date-in-java)

The problem is addressed in Java 7, using the new NIO classes:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html

Obviously to take advantage of this in ANT you'd need to write a custom task or embed a script.

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in [David W.s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14739920/1930509): 
it not works on second run, because the attribute is not overwritten on second run.

Change: `project.setNewProperty` should be `project.setProperty`

Full code snippet:

```xml
<scriptdef name="filedate" language="javascript">
    <attribute name="file"/>
    <attribute name="property"/>
        <![CDATA[
            file_name = attributes.get("file");
            property_to_set = attributes.get("property");

            file = new java.io.File(file_name);
            file_date = file.lastModified();

            date_format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            formated_date = date_format.format(new java.util.Date(file_date));
            project.setProperty(property_to_set, formated_date);
        ]]>
</scriptdef>
```