# How to get file data modification Ant

Tags: java, xml, linux, ant, centos

I am trying to get file date modification usign Ant xml. I am reading files from a folder and I want to get the file modification date. Linux's command to get that info is: stat -c %y *filename*. How can I get the same info using Ant?

My Ant code is something like that:

```
    <basename file="${Files}" property="FileInput"/>

        <length file="${inputFile.dir}/${nomeFileInput}" property="length.fileInput" />
        <echo message="File elab : ${nomeFileInput}" />

<antcallback target="ciclaFile" return="continue"/>
</target>
<target name="ciclaFile" if="${continue}">
    <echo message="Sono in ciclaFile in ${inputFile.dir}" />
    <foreach target="executeImpFile" inheritall="true" inheritrefs="true" param="Files"> 
                           <path>  
                            <sort>
                             <fileset dir="${inputFile.dir}" casesensitive="no">
                             </fileset>
                            </sort>
                          </path>
    </foreach>
</target>
```

Comment: Why do you need the modification date?  Many tasks automatically apply actions based on modification date.

Comment: I need it to compare that date with another one stored in the database which always refer to the file.

Comment: Some of the javascript macros here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714228/ant-get-file-creation-timestamp might help